# Why does this modelica code fail without error?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am attempting to write a modelica package to describe a mixture of ideal gases (in this case, air and fuel vapour). I am doing this myself because I find the media library to be too complex for my purposes. Nonetheless, I am taking inspiration from the media library code. However, after three attempts and restarts, I still cannot get the hang of how modelica works and why everything keeps throwing errors. The code below is the latest attempt, where 'check model' results in 'Internal error Instantiation of v8.gasLibrary.fuelCombustion failed with no error message.'. I cannot figure out why this error occurs. Any help would be much appreciated, the code is below.

In addition, if anyone would have any tips/sources to understand how modelica works, this would be most welcome. Currently, my main source has been 'Modelica by example', which is a great introduction but too superficial to gain robust understanding into modelica, to my opinion.

```
package gasLibrary
 
partial package mixedGas
    replaceable String[:] gasNames = {"nonUsablePackage"};
    parameter Integer nS = size(gasNames,1);
    replaceable gasProperties[nS] properties = {gasProperties()};
    replaceable Modelica.Units.SI.MassFraction[nS] Mi = {1};
    replaceable gasState state = gasState(P = 101.3*10^3, T = 300);

      function getHeatCapacity
        input Modelica.Units.SI.MassFraction[:] Mi;
        replaceable input gasProperties[n] properties;
        output Modelica.Units.SI.HeatCapacity Cv;
      protected
        Modelica.Units.SI.HeatCapacity[:] heatCapacities = {gasProperties.Cv};
      algorithm
        Cv := Mi*heatCapacities;
      end getHeatCapacity;

      function getMolarFractions
        input Modelica.Units.SI.MassFraction[:] Mi;
        replaceable input gasProperties[nS] properties;
        output Real[:] Xi "molar fractions";
      protected
        Modelica.Units.SI.MolarMass[:] MM = {properties.MM};
      algorithm
        totalMoles := sum(Mi / MM);
        Xi := {Mi/MM/totalMoles};
      end getMolarFractions;

      function getTotalMoles
        replaceable input gasProperties[:] properties;
        input Modelica.Units.SI.MassFraction[:] Mi;
        output Real totalMoles;
      protected
        Modelica.Units.SI.MolarMass MM = {properties.MM};
      algorithm
        totalMoles := sum(Mi/MM);
      end getTotalMoles;
    
      function getSpecificVolume
            replaceable input gasProperties[:] properties;
            input Modelica.Units.SI.MassFraction[:] Mi;
            input gasState state;
            output Modelica.Units.SI.SpecificVolume v;
          algorithm
            totalMoles := getTotalMoles(properties, Mi);
            v := totalMoles* Modelica.Constants.R * state.T / state.P;
          end getSpecificVolume;
          function getDensity
            replaceable input gasProperties[:] properties;
            input Modelica.Units.SI.MassFraction[:] Mi;
            input gasState state;
            output Modelica.Units.SI.Density rho;
          algorithm
            rho := 1/getSpecificVolume(properties, Mi, state);
          end getDensity;
end mixedGas;

  record gasProperties
    constant Modelica.Units.SI.MolarMass MM = 0;
    constant Modelica.Units.SI.HeatCapacity Cv = 0;
  end gasProperties;

  record gasState
  Modelica.Units.SI.Pressure P;
  Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature T;
  end gasState;

  package singleGasProperties
  gasProperties O2(MM = 0.032, Cv = 950);
  gasProperties N2(MM = 0.028, Cv = 1150);
  gasProperties CO2(MM = 0.044, Cv = 800);
  gasProperties fuel(MM=0.114, Cv = 2200);
  end singleGasProperties;

  package fuelCombustion
  extends mixedGas;
  
  redeclare String[:] gasNames = {"O2", "N2", "CO2", "fuel"};
  redeclare gasProperties[nS] properties = {singleGasProperties.O2, singleGasProperties.N2, singleGasProperties.CO2, singleGasProperties.fuel};
  redeclare Modelica.Units.SI.MassFraction[nS] Mi = {0.2, 0.8, 0, 0};
  
  end fuelCombustion;
end gasLibrary;
```

I was hoping that everything would check out without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Creating medium models is certainly not the easiest way of getting acquainted with Modelica.

Copying your code into Dymola and performing a package level check reveals a number of errors: undeclared variables, variables that should be constant etc. The same happens when I check the various functions, `getDensity`, `getHeatCapacity`, etc.

I would advise you to perform unit tests of every function inside your library and let the tests help you uncover the problems in each function.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for responding to this issue. I was wondering if you would have some pointers as to how I can best perform unit tests of Modelica code. In things like Python or Matlab it's quite easy to test things by directly interacting with them through the command prompt. In Modelica, it seems to me like I have to build a small model and simulate it to test everything, and then manually verify results from the plots. Are there more efficient methods for performing unit testing in Modelica?

Comment: I think OpenModelica offers a way to do a kind of single-step debugging but I never tried it. I usually write small models to test a particular function or some pieces of code — like you suggest. This works well enough to check for the type of bugs I found in your code.